# How to plot an specific function?

Tags: python

I want to graph this function: f(x) =e^−x/10 sin(πx)
I have tried with this code, but i don't get a coherent graph.

```
t=np.linspace(0,10)
curve1 =np.exp(-t/10)*np.sin(t*np.pi)
plt.plot(t,curve1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `show()` after you call `plot()` to actually view your graph. The following is working code based off of your code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show

t=np.linspace(0,10)
curve1 =np.exp(-t/10)*np.sin(t*np.pi)
plot(t,curve1)
show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you don't get a coherent graph? This code works fine for me, maybe you need to use plt.show()?

```
t=np.linspace(0,10)
curve1 =np.exp(-t/10)*np.sin(t*np.pi)
plt.plot(t,curve1) 
plt.show()
```